# Construct H5 DataSpace to write to DataSet from buffer without Copy

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have a buffer (char array) in memory thats essentially the rows of a csv file.

The example csv file is say

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0 | matt |
| 2 | 2.0 | jack |

For simplicity assume the column C is char arrays of length 5 bytes (4 ascii + null). The datatype of column A is uint8 (1 byte) and column B is float (4 bytes)

After reading the csv I have in memory ('\n') included.

1, 1.0, 'matt', '\n', 2, 2.0, 'jack'

What I would like is to go from that char array holding the raw bytes to an hdf5 file with 3 datasets within it. The datasets are called `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"` respectively. I would like to do this with zero copy going straight from `buffer` to the respective dataset. My gut feeling is that I should be do this through `mem_space` argument of
`H5::DataSet::write` by using a `H5::DataSpace::selectHyperslab`. I just don't understand how to do that. I just don't understand how I am supposed to use `H5::DataSpace::selectHyperslab` here. I also don't know if the hyperslab selection is going to be able to slice around the `'\n'`.

```cpp
#include <H5Cpp.h>

// hex                         | 1  |           1.0         |           matt              |      \n    |  2  |           2.0         |          jack               |
const unsigned char buffer[] = {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3F, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x74, 0x74, 0x00, 0x0A , 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x6A, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x00};

H5::H5File* file = new H5::H5File("example.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);

hsize_t dims[] = {1};
H5::DataSpace* dataspace = new H5::DataSpace(1, dims);

H5::DataSet* A = new H5::DataSet(file->createDataSet("/A", H5::PredType::NATIVE_UINT8, *dataspace));
H5::DataSet* B = new H5::DataSet(file->createDataSet("/B", H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, *dataspace));
H5::DataSet* C = new H5::DataSet(file->createDataSet("/C", H5::PredType::NATIVE_CHAR, *dataspace));

A->write(buffer, H5::PredType::NATIVE_UINT8, ??);
B->write(buffer, H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT, ??);
C->write(buffer, H5::PredType::NATIVE_CHAR, ??);
```

Comment: I don't think data space hyperslabs are the answer here because they work on regular n-dimensional arrays and your data is not. You can't define the stride as byte offsets, only element offsets. For example you would need to add padding so that every float is at an offset that is a multiple of 4. What you might be able to do is create a custom datatype and then [register conversion functions](https://docs.hdfgroup.org/hdf5/develop/group___c_o_n_v.html#ga0a23a3cb9f24bd79fae7d2d8c412a25a) that extract the corresponding member.